# i implemented all thing in searchview but i cant know what is the error

Tags: android

when i click search no result come i tried to search by name but no result i used filterable but i dont no the reason only recyclerview all name appear in activity not the name that i selected i tried everything and hope find solution for that

```
 RecyclerView.Adapter <ClientAdapter.ClientHolder> implements Filterable{ 

 ArrayList <name> mylist;
 Context context;
 ArrayList<name> arraylist;;
 public ClientAdapter (ArrayList<name>mylist,Context context){
    this.mylist=mylist;
    this.context=context;
}
@Override
public ClientHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.clientexp,parent,false);
    ClientHolder holder=new ClientHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ClientHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.img.setImageBitmap(convertToBitmap(mylist.get(position).getImage()));
    holder.Name.setText(mylist.get(position).getName().toString());
    final int idd=mylist.get(position).getId();
    final String id=Integer.toString(idd);
    holder.layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            Intent intent=new Intent(context,DeletePerson.class);
            bundle.putString("id",id);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);


        }
    });

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mylist.size();
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override//charsequance حروف مسلسله
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
            String charString=charSequence.toString();
            if(charString.isEmpty())
            {
                arraylist=mylist;
            }else {
                ArrayList<name>filteredlist=new ArrayList<>();
                for(name filtername:mylist)
                {
                    if(filtername.getName().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase()))
                    {
                        filteredlist.add(filtername);
                    }
                }
                arraylist=filteredlist;
            }
            FilterResults filterResults=new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values=arraylist;
            filterResults.count =arraylist.size();
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            arraylist=(ArrayList<name>)filterResults.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    };
}

public class ClientHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView Name;
    LinearLayout layout;
    ImageView img;
    public ClientHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        Name=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        layout=(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.linear);
        img=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgid);
    }
}
private Bitmap convertToBitmap(byte[] b){

    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);

}


}
```

@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search, menu);

```
    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView   searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
            .getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
            .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

    // listening to search query text change
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            // filter recycler view when query submitted
            adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
            // filter recycler view when text is changed
            adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsIte`enter code here`mSelected(MenuItem item) {



    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_search) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using `mylist` which is the original unfiltered list. and you are filtering `arraylist` which the adapter has nothing to do with it. it does not know about it.
your item are filtered but you are using the wrong list.

```
ArrayList <name> mylist;
ArrayList<name> arraylist;
```

change your construcot to.

```
public ClientAdapter (ArrayList<name>mylist,Context context){
this.mylist=mylist;
this.arraylist=mlist;  //use this as your acual list--> inside onBindViewHolder and getCount()
this.context=context;
 }
```

**Note:**

rename the two lists (originalist and filteredList) for convenience.

Comment: i need to ask question why i didnt use only one arraylist use originallist only why i used filteredList also